# MySQL dump by query

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Is it possible to do `mysqldump` by single `SQL query`?

I mean to dump the **whole** database, like `phpmyadmin` does when you do export to `SQL`

Answer (score 347, accepted):

not mysqldump, but mysql cli...

```
mysql -e "select * from myTable" -u myuser -pxxxxxxxxx mydatabase
```

you can redirect it out to a file if you want :

```
mysql -e "select * from myTable" -u myuser -pxxxxxxxx mydatabase > mydumpfile.txt
```

Update: 
Original post asked if he could dump from the database by query. What he asked and what he meant were different. He really wanted to just mysqldump all tables.

```
mysqldump --tables myTable --where="id < 1000"
```

Comment: You can use the -B (--batch) switch to output as tab delimited, too.

Comment: how to restore this dumped txt file?

Comment: for those trying the mysql -e approach.  I had to customize the script a bit to work for me.  This one requires you to enter the sql password when run.

mysql -e "select * from table WHERE query = 'asdasd'" -u root -p --database=DBNAME > text.txt

Comment: you could just create a new table for the query (CREATE TABLE SELECT), and then dump that table with mysqldump. That way you can easily restore it later.

Comment: for who wants to use mysqldump and restore the file have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2431936/411786

Comment: To import data that is exported with mysql -e with the -B option to output as tab-delimited, run mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by='\t'. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17071108/1676044

Comment: If you want export the data with charset of utf8, please add this config `--default-character-set=utf8`

Comment: If i'm dumping only a *subset of rows* of table (using `--where` option of `mysqldump` and corresponding `SQL` query in `mysql -e..`) to `csv` file, should i expect a difference in performance between the two commands?

Comment: Anyone know how to use backslashes \ in the where clause? need a --where="type LIKE 'Something\Something\Something' ", but doesn't produce inserts on the dump file

Answer (score 281):

This should work

```sh
mysqldump --databases X --tables Y --where="1 limit 1000000"
```

Comment: A better example might be something that actually looks like a where clause, such as --where="myColumn < 1000" - the first million rows of every table seems like a strange thing to request ;)

Comment: @ijw If what you want to do is to take an easily reinsert-able backup of your table, you probably don't need a where clause for anything else than limits.

Comment: @Sagotharan: Well, it's not a query. That's probably why.

Comment: !!WARNING!! mysqldump adds a 'DROP TABLE' command at the top of the exported file. That means if you do a partial export then reimport it, you'll lose everything else. Well, I did.

Comment: Yes, in order to **not delete all the data in your table** when restoring from the saved data file, make sure you add in the `--no-create-info` option.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15058427/1054260) for an example.

Comment: Note that this is not exactly the same as the result of a similar SELECT query: it will not see any data in views.

Answer (score 101):

Dump a table using a where query:

```
mysqldump mydatabase mytable --where="mycolumn = myvalue" --no-create-info > data.sql
```

Dump an entire table:

```
mysqldump mydatabase mytable > data.sql
```

Notes:

- Replace `mydatabase`, `mytable`, and the where statement with your desired values.
- By default, `mysqldump` will include `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements in its output.  Therefore, if you wish to **not delete all the data in your table** when restoring from the saved data file, make sure you use the `--no-create-info` option.
- You may need to add the appropriate `-h`, `-u`, and `-p` options to the example commands above in order to specify your desired database host, user, and password, respectively.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. This answer should be higher up.

Comment: This is what I always use for such use case when I need to dump only certain data - so it's very handy.

Answer (score 80):

You can dump a query as csv like this:

```
SELECT * from myTable
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/querydump.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: What if I want to dump multiple tables.

Comment: This creates a file on the machine on which MySQL database is running. So, if you are querying from a remote console this method fails.

If there is a way of doing it from a remote console as well, please let me know about it.

Comment: where do it save the file?

Comment: @dknight I'm assuming you mean a remote console via a terminal console, in which case you can retrieve the dumped file via`scp` after the connection is terminated. here's an example.

`scp user@remote-server.com:/tmp/querydump.csv ~/local.csv`

Comment: It seems to be insecure: #1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Answer (score 42):

You could use --where option on mysqldump to produce an output that you are waiting for:

```
mysqldump -u root -p test t1 --where="1=1 limit 100" > arquivo.sql
```

At most 100 rows from test.t1 will be dumped from database table.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to export your last n amount of records into a file, you can run the following:

```
mysqldump -u user -p -h localhost --where "1=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100" database table > export_file.sql
```

The above will save the last 100 records into export_file.sql, assuming the table you're exporting from has an auto-incremented id column.

You will need to alter the user, localhost, database and table values. You may optionally alter the id column and export file name.

Answer (score 10):

MySQL Workbench also has this feature neatly in the GUI. Simply run a query, click the save icon next to Export/Import:

[image]

Then choose "SQL INSERT statements (*.sql)" in the list.

[image]

Enter a name, click save, confirm the table name and you will have your dump file.

Comment: and you have 5gb in query select, does not work

Answer (score 3):

Combining much of above here is my real practical example, selecting records based on both  meterid & timestamp. I have needed this command for years. Executes really quickly.

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword main_dbo trHourly --where="MeterID =5406 AND TIMESTAMP<'2014-10-13 05:00:00'" --no-create-info --skip-extended-insert | grep  '^INSERT' > 5406.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

To dump a specific table,

```
mysqldump -u root -p dbname -t tablename --where="id<30" > post.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql Export the query results command line：

```
mysql -h120.26.133.63 -umiyadb -proot123 miya -e "select * from user where id=1" > mydumpfile.txt
```

Comment: it is working for me in ubuntu ,
command:
mysql -h localhost -u root -p dbname -e "select * from users where id=1;select * from staffs where id=1" --xml > /var/www/html/project/backups/db.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dump specific fields from a table this can be handy

1/ create temporary table with your query.

```
create table tmptable select field1, field2, field3 from mytable where filter1 and fileter2 ;
```

2/ dump the whole temporary table. then you have your dump file with your specific fields.

```
mysqldump -u user -p mydatabase tmptable > my-quick-dump.sql
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

here is my mysqldump to select the same relation from different tables:

```
 mysqldump --defaults-file=~/.mysql/datenbank.rc -Q -t -c --hex-blob \
 --default-character-set=utf8 --where="`cat where-relation-ids-in.sql`" \
 datenbank table01 table02 table03 table04 > recovered-data.sql
```

where-relation-ids-in.sql:

```
relation_id IN (6384291, 6384068, 6383414)
```

~/.mysql/datenbank.rc

```
[client]
user=db_user
password=db_password
host=127.0.0.1
```

Remark: If your relation_id file is huge, the comment of the where clause  will be cut in the dump file, but all data is selected correct ;-)

I hope it helps someone ;-)