# mysqldump from a query

Tags: mysql

How can I make a mysql dump for table from a query?

I need something like this..

```
mysqldump -uroot -pxxxx mydb "select * from table where name='1';" >  /tmp/a
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

mysqldump has a `--where` parameter: [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where)

> Dump only rows selected by the given WHERE condition. Quotes around the condition are mandatory if it contains spaces or other characters that are special to your command interpreter.
>
> Examples:
>
> --where="user='jimf'"
>
> -w"userid>1"
>
> -w"userid<1"

I don't know what they use, but [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) can do this too, Just make the query, select all rows and choose the "export" button to the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to insert your query results into a tmp table, then dump that tmp table.

Comment: This solution is better because you can export the result of queries with joins. Mysql can create a table from a select (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html)