# Output mysql column into text file

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv

I have a table on my database named "forumresults". 
This table contain columns;
"id", "fid", "userid", "username", "time", etc....

Now, I want to pull a list from this table automatically by outputting fields only with "fid" 9. I don't want the entire row, I only want it to output the "username" field into a txt/csv file separated by new line.

Also, This command should be running periodically, with an option to remove from file, if that field is no longer in the database.

My website software: vbulletin 4.2.2
Website server: Centos 6.5
MySQL:  5.5.34-MariaDB

p.s. My knowledge in mysql databases is limited to Search & modify with phpmyadmin, only.

Comment: sorry for offtopic, but then you're doomed :) Start by reading something about SQL I guess because that what you're asking is not 1 question, but whole solution ...

Comment: What programming language will you implement this in?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431912/mysqldump-from-a-query ?

Comment: @Leo `mysqldump` doesn't produce CSV.

Comment: @Barmar: It does if one specifies [`--tab`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tab) [`--fields-terminated-by=","`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_fields).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html):

```
SELECT username
INTO   OUTFILE '/path/to/usernames.txt'
LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM   forumresults
WHERE  fid = 9
```

You can even create an [event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/events.html) to perform such an operation on a regular basis.  However, note that:

> The file is created on the server host, so you must have the [`FILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege to use this syntax. ***`file_name`*** cannot be an existing file, which among other things prevents files such as `/etc/passwd` and database tables from being destroyed.