# How to take a backup of year specific records from mysql table to a file?

Tags: mysql

How to take a backup of only last year records from MySQL table to a file?

Comment: Why don't you just move the relevant data into another table and back up that table?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
mysqldump --databases X --tables Y --where="1 limit 1000000"
```

OR mysql cli

mysql -e "select * from myTable" -u myuser -pxxxxxxxxx mydatabase > mydumpfile.txt

Reference
[MySQL dump by query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935556/mysql-dump-by-query)

Answer (score 0):

Actually my requirement is like, we have one table with few years of data(approx 3 lac's records) based on the client requirement we have to keep only current year of data in the table remaining years data we have to take backup to a script and purge that data. I just tried the following code for backup. It's working fine. Please let me know is there any other way to do this simply.

mysqldump --add-lock test Employee -u root -n -t "--where=end_date between '1998-02-01' and '1998-08-30'" > sample.sql