# Error In MySQL Dump And Need The mysqldump output in a php string.

Tags: mysql

```
mysql --user=root --password=root --extended-insert=false --where="ID in (1,2) AND post_author='1'" wp_7 wp_posts > 1.sql;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
 --user=root --password=root --extended-insert=false --where="ID in (1,2) A' at
line 1
```

Also, I need the output of the mysqldump in a php string. not in a file.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935556/mysql-dump-by-query I can't help you with the PHP bit.

Comment: You have to use mysqldump, not mysql

Comment: @fancyPants I replaced mysql with mysqldump and run it again in mysql console. it again gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dump = shell_exec('mysqldump --user=user --password=asdasd --host=localhost db_name');
```