# Insert Statement with result record values

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 50 columns, and the table has more than one lakh records.
My requirement is to get few desired records from the table and insert into another machine's database table.

Is there a way to extract the desired result records along with Insert statement?  I tried doing with exporting the data, but it fetches all the records.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: If it is mysql: MySQL dump by query
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935556/mysql-dump-by-query

Comment: You can also use[select into file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html)

Comment: Thank you for the responses, will try both the options