# server-side code to export an entire database from mysql

Tags: mysql

I know that you can export a database from phpmyadmin. Is there a way of sending a an sql query that will export all the tables with information?

the script will go as follows:

1. user fill in a form and sends it to the server
2. server creates a database
3. server populates that database with tables
4. server selects all the tables
5. server sends that back to the user as an sql file to download

For example, in phpmyadmin you can select a database and "export all tables" as SQL.

I think I'm looking for a select statement something along the lines of: `SELECT all tables FROM database`

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935556/mysql-dump-by-query)

Comment: is there a way you can do that with a query?

Comment: SELECT *  FROM db
    INTO OUTFILE 'example.txt'; this export as .txt, however exporting as .sql files i guess there is no other way but using mysqldump.