# Mysql dump into SQL format with mysql -e?

Tags: mysql

I have been looking for solution to export table with specific fields/columns. 
I am using Ubuntu commandline to do that. Luckily [MySQL dump by query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935556/mysql-dump-by-query) help me achieve my goal with

```
mysql -e "select * from myTable" -u myuser -pxxxxxxxx mydatabase > mydumpfile.txt
```

But, I am getting plain text file. I want to get file dumped as SQL format.
So can I get dumped file with ***mydumpfile.sql*** instead of mydumpfile.txt?

Comment: There is an updated answer in the page you mentioned, use the mysqldump command instead.

Comment: I assume you don't mean just changing the file extension? Do you mean insert statements?

Comment: @SimonMC.Cheng How to use SELECT in mysqldump? I was told it was not possible in mysqldump?

Comment: Not sure what is your problem... if you want to have sql statement output with table schema, you can use something like... [mysqldump mydatabase mytable --where="mycolumn = myvalue > dump.sql]

Comment: @SimonMC.Cheng I want SELECT statement in mysqldump which is apparently not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want full insert statements you have to use `mysqldump`. if you want comma separated (CSV) you have to use `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` from the mysql client.

mysql -e does a query on the database and shows result in the console. Your redirect '>' at the end means that display get's saved to a file. That saved file is not very usefull for programming work. It's only for humans.

Comment: I think CSV is only option I am left. When I try that it says access denied. Should run on commandline or inside mysql?

Comment: can do with in the console but you don't have the select into outfile permission (or so it seems)