# MySQL dump by long query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Question is similar to [MySQL dump by query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935556/mysql-dump-by-query) but with the difference that the SELECT query I want is super long (almost 1000 lines)

So just to put it in perspective,

```
mysql -e "SELECT * from myTable WHERE id NOT IN (*lots of specific id numbers*)" -u myuser -pxxxxxxxxx mydatabase > output.txt
```

How can I achieve this?

I also tried going into the DB itself and running the query there and adding `INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/querydump.csv'` in the end but get the error;

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' (using password: YES)

Any helpful tips please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip: always read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html): "*The file is created on the server host, so you must have the `FILE` privilege to use this syntax.*"

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't manage to do this from server side due to the long query output, found a workaround by using MySQL Workbench which is a very helpful tool to use in such cases[image]